# How to load a large h5 file in memory?

Tags: numpy, hdfs, hdf5, h5py, chunking

I have a large h5 file with 5-dimensional numpy array in HDFS. File size is ~130Gb. I am facing memory issues while loading the file with process gets killed with OOM Error even though machine has 256Gb RAM. How can I write the file in chunks and load back in chunks? I looked around and found that h5py provides method to chunk the dataset like so but how do I load back the data in chunks? Also will it work if the file resides in HDFS?

```
dset = f.create_dataset("Images2", (100,480,640), 'f', chunks=True)
```

Idea is to load the file in batches for less I/O time as well as memory issues. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Even without chunks you can load slices, e.g. `dset[33]` or `dset[22:55]`.  This is exlained in the `h5py` docs.

Answer (score 3):

Two similar (but different) h5py I/O concepts are mentioned in the answer and comments above:

- HDF5 **Chunking** is used to enable chunked I/O for improved performance. Chunking *may not help* if you get an OOM error when you try to read a large dataset with insufficient memory.
- NumPy style **Slicing** is used to read a slice of the data from the drive to memory (or write a slice of data to the drive). Slicing is the key to avoid OOM errors when reading very large files.
- Also, when creating very large datasets, you generally need to make
  it resizeable. You can allocate an initial size, then use the ".resize()" method to increase the size on disk.

I wrote a simple example that shows how to use both slicing and chunking. It loads 100 images at a time into a resizeable dataset. It then closes the file and reopens (read-only) to read 100 images at a time into a NumPy array.

Effective chunking requires appropriate size/shape and is based on your array shape and I/O needs. I set the chunk size/shape in my example to match the size of 100 image array I was writing/reading.

This example should get you started. You will need to modify to use a 5-d array/dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

with h5py.File('SO_64645940.h5','w') as h5w:
    img_ds = h5w.create_dataset('Images', shape=(100,480,640), dtype='f', maxshape=(None,480,640),chunks=(10,480,640))

    next_img_row = 0    
    arr = np.random.random(100*480*640).reshape(100,480,640)
    for cnt in range(1,10):
#        print(cnt,img_ds.len(),next_img_row)
        if img_ds.len() == next_img_row :
            img_ds.resize(100*cnt,axis=0)
            print('new ds size=',img_ds.len())
        h5w['Images'][next_img_row:next_img_row+100] = arr
        next_img_row += 100
    
    
with h5py.File('SO_64645940.h5','r') as h5r:
     for cnt in range(10):
         print('get slice#',str(cnt))
         img_arr = h5r['Images'][cnt*100:(cnt+1)*100]
```

Answer (score 0):

Chunking in HDF5 means that the data is not stored contigous, but in chunks.
See information here: https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage
--> So this doesn't help you with your problem.

The solution might be that you build a function yourself to load the data chunkwise.
I made it for example this way for getting the data chunked:

```
def get_chunked(data, chunk_size=100):
    for i in give_chunk(len(data), chunk_size):
        chunked_array = data[i]
        yield chunked_array

def give_chunk(length, chunk_size):
    it = iter(range(length))
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(it, chunk_size))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
```

For writing the data to HDF5 you can create the dataset first and then write the data chunk wise with slicing, see h5py documentation: https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

I really can recommend this book for basic knowledge about HDF5: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-and-hdf5/9781491944981/